# How/when to use owner locks with sql persistence in WF 4.5

Tags: workflow-foundation

I cannot find info on how the mechanism works or what the right approachis, my scenario:

-WorklfowApplication instance loads a xaml file
-The workflow runs and goes idle by bookmark, unloads and is then automatically persisted
-At a later stage a new WorkflowApplication instance loads the workflow and resumes the bookmark
-The workflow completes and unloads

This all works fine if I never bother to do any cleanup ie. I create a lock only at the time of starting the workflow and then when resuming the bookmark I don't create a lock BUT I get loads of records left behind in 'LockOwnersTable'.

I am hoping someone can explain when locks should be created and released and what the 'Lock Expiration' means in 'LockOwnersTable'.

Comment: I have done some more tests and my workflow persists and resumes just fine without any of the code that creates/deletes instance owners/locks. Right now I understand even less about why this mechanism is necessary...

Comment: How did you suppress creation and deletion of instance owners/locks? Can it be done with WF4.0 as well ?